# ActiveMQ queue authentication by certificate

Tags: apache, activemq-classic

Currently our ActiveMQ queue authentication config takes a username and password to authenticate, but that is not desirable since we're distributing the client (that posts to ActiveMQ) to 1000s of workstations and I don't want to have to hardcode a username and password in the client code for obvious security reasons.

We have certificates on each client machine, and we have ActiveMQ configured to use the client certificates for transport level authentication.  Is there a way to 'pass through' the clients that are authenticated by their certificates such that they are authorized to write to the queue without also needing a username and password for the queue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure about this but I believe following steps can help you to implement the authentication and authorization for your ActiveMQ clients.

1) Use `JaasCertificateAuthenticationPlugin`

2) Override `CertificateLoginModule` and provide implementation to get user groups depending upon the certificate details.

3) Use these user groups in queue authorization mappings.

Related links -

http://activemq.apache.org/security.html

http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/CertificateLoginModule-does-not-appear-to-receive-certificates-td2363433.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.  Too bad there doesn't seem to be xml config options.